# Mark True from conditions satisfy on two consecutive values till another two consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a float column in a dataframe. And I want to add another boolean column which will be True if condition satisfies on two consecutive values till another condition satisfies on next two consecutive values.

For Example I have a data-frame which look like this:

| index | Values % |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 14 |
| 5 | 18 |
| 6 | 30 |
| 7 | 54 |
| 8 | 73 |
| 9 | 100 |
| 10 | 100 |
| 11 | 100 |
| 12 | 100 |
| 13 | 100 |

Now I want to mark True from where two consecutive values satisfies the condition `df['Values %'] >= 10` till next two consecutive values satisfies the next condition i.e. `df[Values %] == 100`.

So the final result will look like something this:

| index | Values % | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | False |
| 1 | 5 | False |
| 2 | 11 | False |
| 3 | 9 | False |
| 4 | 14 | False |
| 5 | 18 | True |
| 6 | 30 | True |
| 7 | 54 | True |
| 8 | 73 | True |
| 9 | 100 | True |
| 10 | 100 | True |
| 11 | 100 | False |
| 12 | 100 | False |
| 13 | 100 | False |

Comment: @mozway do you have bettwer idea？

Comment: @G.G I provided an answer, you tell me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# give 2 consecutive values ≥ 10
m1 = df['Values %'].ge(10).rolling(2).min().eq(1)
# give 2 consecutive 100
m2 = df['Values %'].eq(100).rolling(2).min().eq(1)
# get values before (including) first m2 True
m3 = (~m2).shift(fill_value=True).cummin()

# get values between the first m1 True 
df['Flag'] = m1.cummax() & m3
```

Output:

```
    index  Values %   Flag
0       0         0  False
1       1         5  False
2       2        11  False
3       3         9  False
4       4        14  False
5       5        18   True
6       6        30   True
7       7        54   True
8       8        73   True
9       9       100   True
10     10       100   True
11     11       100  False
12     12       100  False
13     13       100  False
```

If you need the logic repeated on several groups:

```
# give 2 consecutive values ≥ 10
m1 = df['Values %'].ge(10).rolling(2).min().eq(1)
# give 2 consecutive 100
m2 = df['Values %'].eq(100).rolling(2).min().eq(1)

# set up grouper
group = (m2.shift()&~m2).cumsum()

# get values before (including) first m2 True
m3 = ((~m2).groupby(group, group_keys=False)
           .apply(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=True).cummin())
     )

# get values between the first m1 True 
df['Flag'] = m1.groupby(group).cummax() & m3
```

Output:

```
    index   Values %   Flag
0        0         0  False
1        1         5  False
2        2        11  False
3        3         9  False
4        4        14  False
5        5        18   True
6        6        30   True
7        7        54   True
8        8        73   True
9        9       100   True
10      10       100   True
11      11       100  False
12      12       100  False
13      13       100  False
14       0         0  False
15       1         5  False
16       2        11  False
17       3         9  False
18       4        14  False
19       5        18   True
20       6        30   True
21       7        54   True
22       8        73   True
23       9       100   True
24      10       100   True
25      11       100  False
26      12       100  False
27      13       100  False
```

Intermediates:

```
    index   Values %   Flag     m1     m2  group     m3
0        0         0  False  False  False      0   True
1        1         5  False  False  False      0   True
2        2        11  False  False  False      0   True
3        3         9  False  False  False      0   True
4        4        14  False  False  False      0   True
5        5        18   True   True  False      0   True
6        6        30   True   True  False      0   True
7        7        54   True   True  False      0   True
8        8        73   True   True  False      0   True
9        9       100   True   True  False      0   True
10      10       100   True   True   True      0   True
11      11       100  False   True   True      0  False
12      12       100  False   True   True      0  False
13      13       100  False   True   True      0  False
14       0         0  False  False  False      1   True
15       1         5  False  False  False      1   True
16       2        11  False  False  False      1   True
17       3         9  False  False  False      1   True
18       4        14  False  False  False      1   True
19       5        18   True   True  False      1   True
20       6        30   True   True  False      1   True
21       7        54   True   True  False      1   True
22       8        73   True   True  False      1   True
23       9       100   True   True  False      1   True
24      10       100   True   True   True      1   True
25      11       100  False   True   True      1  False
26      12       100  False   True   True      1  False
27      13       100  False   True   True      1  False
```

Comment: have bug if value is：   0
5
11
9
14
18
30
54
73
100
100
100
100
100
0
5
11
9
14
18
30
54
73
100
100
100
100
100

Comment: @G.G why? this sets the True between the first double value and the first double 100 which was my understanding of the question. If you want to handle groups, then use a groupby (see update)

Comment: ok ,well done!tks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly the second part of your question is supposed to work but here is how to achieve the first.

**example data**

```
s = pd.Series([0,5,11,9,14,18,2,14,16,18])
```

**solution**

```
# create true/false series for first condition and take cumulative sum
x = (s >= 10).cumsum()

# compare each element of x with 2 elements before.  There will be a difference of 2 for elements which belong to streak of 2 or more True
condition = x - x.shift(2) == 2
```

`condition` looks like this

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: actually I wanted a range from one to another point

Comment: ok, I don't know what that means but hopefully you will find something useful above. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have a rather inefficient way of doing this. It's not vectorised, so not ideal, but it works:

```
# Convert the values column to a 1D NumPy array for ease of use.
values = df["Values %"].tolist()
values_np = np.array(values)

# Initialize flags 1D array to be the same size as values_np. Initially set to all 0s. Uses int form of booleans, i.e. 0 = False and 1 = True.
flags = np.zeros((values_np.shape[0]), dtype=int)

# Iterate from 1st (not 0th) row to last row.
for i in range(1, values_np.shape[0]):
    # First set flag to 1 (True) if meets the condition that consecutive values are both >= 10.
    if values_np[i] >= 10 and values_np[i-1] >= 10:
        flags[i] = 1

    # Then if consecutive values are both larger than 100, set flag to 0 (False).
    if values_np[i] >= 100 and values_np[i-1] >= 100:
        flags[i] = 0

# Turn flags into boolean form (i.e. convert 0 and 1 to False and True).
flags = flags.astype(bool)

# Add flags as a new column in df.
df["Flags"] = flags
```

One thing -- my method gives False for row 10, because both row 9 and row 10 >= 100. If this is not what you wanted, let me know and I can change it so that the flag is True only if the previous two values *and* the current value (3 consecutive values) are all >= 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame,Flag,pos=2):
    if(len(dd)>2):
        df1.loc[dd.iloc[pos].name,'Flag']=Flag

df11=df1.assign(col1=(~(df1['Values%'].ge(10))).cumsum()).groupby('col1').apply(function1,Flag=True)\
    .assign(col2=(~(df1['Values%'].eq(100))).cumsum()).groupby('col2').apply(function1,Flag='e',pos=3)\
    .pipe(lambda dd:df1).ffill()
df11.assign(Flag=df11.Flag.mask(df11.Flag.ne(True),False))
```

or:

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    idx1=dd['Values'].loc[lambda ss:ss.ge(10)&ss.shift().ge(10)].index.min()
    dd.loc[idx1:,'Flag']=True
    return dd

col1=(df1['Values'].shift().eq(100)&df1['Values'].shift(2).eq(100)).cumsum()
df1.groupby(col1).apply(function1).fillna(False)
```

out：

```
 Values%   Flag
0         0  False
1         5  False
2        11  False
3         9  False
4        14  False
5        18   True
6        30   True
7        54   True
8        73   True
9       100   True
10      100   True
11      100  False
12      100  False
13      100  False
```